# Unable to run python script in virtualenv using bash script

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, conda

I want to run a python script in in-built anaconda environment tensorflow_p36. To check if it is in virtual environment or not, I am using command `pip -V`.

---

My first attempt at bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source activate tensorflow_p36
python /home/ec2-user/abc/temp.py
pip -V
```

*Note: `tensorflow_p36` being an in-built environment, does not require to be called from specific `/env/bin` directory. It can be activated from any directory. I think it's a feature of [Amazon Deep Learning AMIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-tensorflow.html).*

---

My second attempt at bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pythonEnv="/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/"
source ${pythonEnv}bin/activate
${pythonEnv}bin/python /home/ec2-user/abc/temp.py
pip -V
```

*Note: When I try to run `source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/activate` command in terminal, the environment isn't being activated.*

---

Each time, I am getting the same result:

pip 9.0.1 from /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Whereas, I should be getting:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Can someone please explain how do I activate virtual environment and run a python script from that environment? I need to use this particular environment because of the dependencies installed in it.

**Extra info:**
Not sure if it matters, but the tensorflow_p36 is a [conda environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment), not a virtualenv.

Comment: Are you sure the venv was built to include its own `pip`?

Comment: When I go into `tensorflow_p36` using terminal, that's when I get the output `pip 9.0.1 from /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)` Hope I answered your question correctly.

Comment: Does it help if you do `hash -r pip` right after you activate the venv?

Comment: I don't know what is the purpose of hash, can you tell me how it can help in this scenario?

Comment: I just ran your first script--- an utterly analogous version--- without the tensorflow_p36 on the second line. I put it in the bin directory of the virtual environment. It works fine. The pip version printout shows that it is the one from my virtualenv.

Comment: I don't understand what could possibly be wrong in my case then, is it because these are conda environments? https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the difference. Maybe there are comments at the top of the Conda activate script that will clarify things. There are some for the Python virtualenv.

Comment: The conda doc to which you referred me says that the `myenv` in `source activate myenv` is a path name. Maybe you just need the full path, notwithstanding the fact that you're already in the right directory.

Comment: `tensorflow_p36` and others does not require to be called from specific paths, it can be called from any directory. (guess that's a conda built-in environment features). I just tried `source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/activate
` in terminal and it is not activating that environment. You just helped me find another problem here.

Comment: `hash -r` tells Bash to forget its hashed path and search for the binary again using the regular `PATH` resolution.

Comment: Makes sense, I just tried, it is still the same. I can confidently say that environment isn't being activated because my python script would only run in that environment.

Comment: What do you get for `type -all activate`?

Comment: I don't know what this code did, see the results: https://jpst.it/1bRwb
It all works now! Can you explain what was the problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense really. But good if that helped.

Comment: @tripleee, as you saw in my latest post, I think the problem was because of the root user. I was using ec2-user only but somehow root access was hindering it. If you wish to put it as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Erm, not sure I get it, the script doesn't work when you are root but works if you are ec2-user? Maybe just self-answer, you can accept your own answer though not immediately.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant to accept as answer "the script doesn't work when you are root but works if you are ec2-user". Will see if someone else wants to shed some light on it, otherwise I'll put it as self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works with `virtualenv`. Create environment:

`virtualenv -p python 3.6 tensorflow_p36`

Then change the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/tensorflow_p36/bin/activate
python /home/ec2-user/abc/temp.py
```

I believe the confusion has to do with the fact that you are using `anaconda` and not `virtualenv` to create a python environment. These two tools work differently.

If you are using an EC2 instance, why not to install `tensorflow_p36` globally anyway?